# How do I get `NumberFormatter` to output parentheses for negative values?

Tags: java, formatting, icu, numberformatter

Fairly common usage, one wants negative numbers formatted with parentheses around them instead of a minus sign.

So I tried adding this:

```
    override fun toString(): String {
        return NumberFormatter.withLocale(Locale.ROOT)
            .notation(Notation.compactShort())
            .unit(currency)
            .precision(Precision.currency(Currency.CurrencyUsage.STANDARD))
 
            // NEW!
            .sign(NumberFormatter.SignDisplay.ACCOUNTING)
 
            .format(rawValue)
            .toString()
    }
```

```
Expected :A$ (23.89)
Actual   :-A$ 23.89
```

So it seems on the surface as if the API is there, but doesn't have any effect on the output.

So far, I have also tried:

- `.sign(NumberFormatter.SignDisplay.ACCOUNTING_NEGATIVE)`
- `.sign(NumberFormatter.SignDisplay.ACCOUNTING_ALWAYS)`

Comment: Code blocks inside bullet points work during preview but not on the final page? How?!

Comment: *Use the locale-dependent accounting format on negative numbers* - maybe use a different locale?

Comment: @ScaryWombat OK it is somehow related to that. So this is awkward, I wanted to specifically use `ROOT` locale because it's for `toString`, not for displaying to the user. If I instead pass in `en_AU` then it does put in the parentheses. I wonder why it doesn't do it for root... I guess if it's going to be like this, an option might be to throw up hands and just not pretty print it.

Comment: @DevilsHnd-退した yeah but fenced works in the preview and then not on the final page, which is still weird. Clearly it's understood if the preview works?

Comment: After some more fiddling I see that specifying the locale gives "(A$23.89)" which is still not "A$ (23.89)" anyway. So maybe it's just one of those things where expecting the formatter to work was unrealistic.